# Trying to change textContent of span element

Tags: javascript

Trying to count number of characters in text field. The following code does not change the span elements textContent. How do I change the textContent to the text fields string lenght? [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNgMdRJ?editors=1010)

HTML

```
<label for="text">Enter your text below.</label>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

<p>You've written <strong><span id="character-count">0</span> characters</strong>.</p>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

  var elem = document.querySelector('#text');
  var text = elem.textContent;
  document.querySelector('#character-count').textContent = text.length;

});
```

Comment: Since `elem` refers to a `<textarea>`, you need `var text = elem.value` instead

Comment: How `keydown` is giving you the correct *length*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change   `var text = elem.textContent;` to `var text = elem.value;`

Comment: How `keydown` is giving the correct length?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  var textArea = document.querySelector('#text');
  var count = document.querySelector('#character-count');

  var text = textArea.value;
  count.innerText = text.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript will be like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

  var elem = document.getElementById('text');
  var text = elem.value;
  console.log(text);
  var count = document.querySelector('#character-count');
  count.textContent = text.length;
  console.log(text.length);

});
```